# jasmine button click event is not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, bdd

I am using jasmine framework to test my html/javascript code.
I have a button and I want to trigger click event on this button.
Once the button is click then the button will set to disabled mode.
Mamnually this works fine.

But the below jasmine code fails to click the button.

```
it("should disable clicking of Edit Setup", function () {
  setup = $("#editSystemSetup");
  // setup.trigger( "click" );
  setup.click();
  console.log(">>" + setup[0].attributes.length);
  expect(setup.attr('disabled')).toBeTruthy(); 
});
```

Once the click is generated then I am expecting that element gets added with disabled="disabled" attribute.

But this is not gettting added . Which means the click is not happening.

Comment: Setup a breakpoint in your code. Is it actually not firing the event? Is the ID correct? Is that element in your DOM that you're using to test? Is your code that wires up the event executing before your test?

Comment: All are proper . I validated this through debug mode.

Comment: `Setup` is not the same as `setup`. Could you also please provide the click handler code that set the disabled attribute.

Comment: Thanks . I found the root cause . The code which sets the element to be disabled is not getting called . I am analyzing on this.

Comment: This was what @krillgar already asked as the first question: *Is it actually not firing the event?*...